# crashlytics developer tools error when building android -gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I'm trying to build an android gradle project using eclipse, but i get this error when building the project using the command line:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesRelease'.
 > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
 option to get more log output.

 BUILD FAILED
```

I'm using gradle version 1.10 also tried gradle version 1.12 but i get the same error

and here is my build.gradle file :

```
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
                maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
                classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
                classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
            }
        }
        apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
        apply plugin: 'android'
        apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        }

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 19
            buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
            lintOptions.checkReleaseBuilds false

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 7
                targetSdkVersion 19
            }

            signingConfigs {
                release {
                    storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }

            buildTypes {
              debug {

               ext.enableCrashlytics = false
               buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_CRASHES", "false"
              }

              release {
                 buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG_CRASHES", "true"
                 runProguard true
                 proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
                 signingConfig signingConfigs.release
              }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
            compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Run with --info or --debug to see more details about the error

Answer (score 38):

Had a similar error trying to use Fabric's Twitter Kit

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricCleanupResourcesDevDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

Detailed error

> ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: XXXXXXXXX. 
>   Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
>   Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.

After login in [Fabric](https://fabric.io/login), download the AndroidStudio plugin and let it configure everything all worked fine.

(Btw, I really don't like this setup flow)

EDIT: It also can be done without install the AndroidStudio plugin. Follow these instructions from the Fabric site https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks.  

  Additional info for all: Once you install the plugin, open the plugin and install crashlytics 2.5.5. It prompts a question - whether gradle files should be updated. Choose yes. Crashlytics errors get resolved after gradle sync is done.

Comment: Screenshot
<img src="https://doc-00-9k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6f495etelu18cv1n54ins4pgr9nlp4r4/ftis1u234rh5ekk6p8ajhahjtdrasjsj/1461031200000/16366544051894029835/16366544051894029835/0B0s7T4EnNAMrazB5YWZkc04yR2M?e=view&nonce=oudkpnin98sao&user=16366544051894029835&hash=mc9dbn80macu7o0mqofdgnu1b2eb0vga" width="100" height="100">

Comment: If none of the above works for you just open the build.gradle class and comment the following as:

//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Answer (score 20):

This is not a solution to the original question, but you can also run into this error another way. If you are following docs for the [Gradle Advanced Setup](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html) you might have included the following code

```
debug {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

Now if you are testing your application you may have tried to set `ext.enableCrashlytics = true` instead. Apparently this will cause errors for Crashlytics though and is not a valid value for this variable.

So if you want Crashlytics enabled for debug builds you'll need to comment out this line while you are testing or remove it altogether.

Comment: Superb man  .. You answer the actual solution to the problem.

Answer (score 13):

By adding this line to your Application's Manifest inside  tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

I resolved this issue

Comment: note, if you use: android:value="@string/your key" you also get the error

Comment: I solved the error with this, next time I'll finish the tutorial before looking for an answer in stack overflow.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue by replacing "io.fabric.ApiKey" with "com.crashlytics.ApiKey" in AndroidManifest.xml (I don't like to change the Crashlytics lib). So the final one is:

```
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
     android:value="xxxxxxxx" />
```

Comment: Alternatively, make sure you have the api key in your fabric.properties file

Answer (score 5):

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
     android:value="your key" />
```

I had simillar issue. Just add these line to your Android manifest file.

Comment: this is solution +1

Comment: note, if you use: android:value="@string/your key" you also get the error

Answer (score 1):

So I was having this issue and resolved it.

Basically, I was trying to use @string/crashlytics_key_prod, instead of putting in the actual key.

Replacing "@string/crashlytics_key_prod" by the actual key in the manifest resolved this issue for me.